# display count for a column which is primary key in another table

Tags: mysql

Take 2 tables as input - Employee and Contact as:

```
Employee  
ID  Name  
1   Anshika   
2   Arnav   
3   Ishita  
4   Iti  

Contact  
ID  Mobile No.  
1   1234  
2   2345  
4   3456  
2   4532  
1   5674
```

Display output as:

```
ID      COUNT  
1       2  
2       2  
3       0  
4       1
```

I wrote:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM Contact GROUP BY id;
```

which gave output as:

```
ID COUNT  
1 2  
2 2  
4 1
```

but I want that `3 0` record also in the output.

Comment: You want the count of contacts of every employee, right ?

Comment: yes..
I want the output as in the original question

Comment: Removed salutation + improved formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work for you :
**

```
SELECT nameemp.id, 
COUNT(Contact.ID) AS total
FROM nameemp 
LEFT JOIN Contact
ON nameemp.id = Contact.id
GROUP BY nameemp.id
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get yourself familiar with different kinds of `JOIN` clauses in SQL (check out [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) for example). This is the solution to your question however:

```
SELECT Employee.ID, COUNT(*)
  FROM Employee
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact
    ON Employee.ID = Contact.ID
  GROUP BY Employee.ID
```